# Unable to add reference to “Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query” or “Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query” in ASP .NET Web Service

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, keywordquery

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace UserProfilesCSOM
 {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("<serverRelativeUrl>"))
        {
            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(siteCollection);
            keywordQuery.QueryText = "*";
            keywordQuery.SourceId = new Guid("B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31");
            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
            ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
            resultTableCollection = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
            ResultTable resultTable = resultTableCollection.FirstOrDefault();
            DataTable dataTable = resultTable.Table;
        } 

        // TODO: Add error handling and input validation.
    }
}
```

}

I'm using above code to retrieve users from user profile in Console application.
I have added all the assembly still it shows error

**Unable to add reference to “Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query” or “Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query” in ASP .NET Web Service**

I had go through this [Article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6869667b-a02f-48f4-9598-d64208f0a6ee/unable-to-add-reference-to-microsoftofficeserversearchquery-or?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious), but it not helped

Comment: What SP Version do you use? What .Net Version do you use? Where is the VS reference pointing at? Is there a reason you are mixing CSOM and SSOM .dlls? Why do you have multiple references to `Microsoft.SharePoint;`?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013. .net version 4.5. the reason behind mixing .dlls is I had tried to use CSOM before on same .cs file, so I had forget to remove